# How to calculate vertex normals of a cylinder?

Tags: opengl, vertex, normals

I have the following cylinder, I am drawing a worm in opengl and I want to calculate the vertex normals.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate normals for every face (triangle) and save it somewhere. Now for every vertex you have several faces that share the vertex (typicaly 6 on your picture). Your final vertex normal is an average of the faces' normals. For 6 faces, you calculate:

```
int faceCount = 6;
float sum = 0.0f;
for(int face = 0; face < faceCount; ++face)
    sum += faceNormals[face].x;
normal.x = sum / faceCount;
// and so on for y and z
```

Don't forget to normalize the resulting vector, so that its length is 1.

NOTE: Don't put `faceNormals` in an array like this. In a real code you probably want to have a single `vector`-like container of all normals and some logic saying which normals are relevant for which vertex.

Comment: should this actually work? for my test it doesnt seem to work... this is what i did: `normal.x = (V1.x+V2.x+V3.x)/3.0f` (for triangle) and then i normalized in the end. what did i do wrong?

Comment: @Rookie This is not a formula for calculating a triangle normal out of its vertices. For this you need a [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). My answer is about making an average of several normal vectors.

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood you, since i understood the OP asking how to calculate normals, not how to calculate smooth normals...

Comment: @Fiktik: That's how you calculate the normals in the general case. On a cylinder, you can get exact normals, because it is a mathematically defined construct.

Answer (score 3):

For every point on a cylinder ring, `vertexNormal = normalize(vertexPosition - ringCenter);`

Or you could calculate them normally, where normal is normalized sum of all face normals for every face that contains this vertex.

Comment: Create one normal per vertex at the same time as you create the vertex using the above formula. This will work for a cylinder as described.